# Values assigned differently in seemingly identical dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

Somehow my two identical nested dictionaries (a dictionary containing dictionaries), created through different means, act differently when I try to assign a new value to a key.

```
d = {'a': {'item': None},'b': {'item': None},'c': {'item': None}}
```

The first dictionary is created manually, while the second one is created through this code:

```
data = {"item" : None}
keys = ["a","b","c"]
d2 = dict()
for i in range(len(keys)):
    d2[keys[i]] = data
```

Both of these give seemingly identical dictionaries.

```
print d
{'a': {'item': None}, 'c': {'item': None}, 'b': {'item': None}}
print d2
{'a': {'item': None}, 'c': {'item': None}, 'b': {'item': None}}
```

Everything seems good so far, but when I try to change the value of any of the keys, this happens:

```
d["a"]["item"] = "1"
d2["a"]["item"] = "1"
print d
{'a': {'item': '1'}, 'c': {'item': None}, 'b': {'item': None}}
print d2
{'a': {'item': '1'}, 'c': {'item': '1'}, 'b': {'item': '1'}}
```

I've tried everything I can think of and I can't find anyone that has had a similar problem. It just doesn't makes sense, why would it change the value in all three of the inside dictionaries? I hope you guys can help.
I'm using Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `dict2 = dict1`, you are not making a copy of `dict1`, it results in `dict2` being just another name for `dict1`.

You can do this using `deepcopy`:

```
data = {"item" : None}
keys = ["a","b","c"]
d2 = dict()

for i in range(len(keys)):
    d2[keys[i]] =  copy.deepcopy(data)
```

But if you have data like :

```
data = {"item1" : None, "item2":{"Book":none}}
```

another `dictionary` inside your data `dictionary`, you must have to use `deepcopy` like above.

Otherwise, there are different way to copy your `dict`. Like

```
d2[keys[i]] =  copy.copy(data)
d2[keys[i]] =  dict(data)
d2[keys[i]] =  data.copy()
```

You can use any to copy your `dict`. Just use `deepcopy` when you have nested `dict`

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a unique dict for each entry, like so:

```
keys = ["a","b","c"]
d2 = dict()
for i in range(len(keys)):
    d2[keys[i]] = {"item" : None}
```

Also you might prefer a more pythonic way:

```
>>> {k:{'item':None} for k in ['a','b','c']}
{'a': {'item': None}, 'c': {'item': None}, 'b': {'item': None}}
```